# remove data after aprticular key word from excel cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have some data in my excel cells like

**"35 xxxxxx, yyyy, zzzzz 1AA 
Call 01234 567899 xxxxxxxxxxxxx_highlighting 01234 567899  FREE  end_of_the_skype_highlighting Contact agent Ideally located in the centre of bla bla bla bla bla, they ... more "**

I want delete all data which appeared  after **Call 01234 567899**. here  numbers are not fixed. phone numbers xchanges to every cell
How can i delete all Data

Thanks
Narasappa.

Comment: Look into `LEFT` and `SEARCH`, something in the realm of `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("Call 01234 567899",A1)-1)` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks but my numbers which appeared after Call are not fixed they are variables

Comment: i got answer this way =LEFT(A1,FIND("Call",A1)-1)                      
=MID(A1,FIND("Call",A1)+4,14)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to rely on the regular expressions library or write a function that uses Instr to find call, appends everything to the left to a temporary string, then iterates over the series of numbers afterwards.  Next, once you read past those series - use the mid function on the original string from that point onwards, essentially skipping the sub, "call" string.  It could get cumbersome, and it could be error prone.

My recommendation is to use Regex, as the following should work:

```
sString = "35 xxxxxx, yyyy, zzzzz 1AA Call 01234 567899 xxxxxxxxxxxxx_highlighting 01234 567899 FREE end_of_the_skype_highlighting Contact agent Ideally located in the centre of bla bla bla bla bla, they ... more"
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Pattern = "Call\s\d+\s\d+"
    msgbox regEx.Replace(sString, "")
```